# why id is found at position 1 in str.indexof() in js

Tags: javascript, string

let str = 'Widget with id';

alert( str.indexOf('Widget') ); // 0, because 'Widget' is found at the beginning

alert( str.indexOf('widget') ); // -1, not found, the search is case-sensitive

alert( str.indexOf("id") ); // 1

Comment: because it found the index of the first instance of `id` which is in `Widget`

Comment: Please explain what surprises you about the fact that "id" is found within "Widget". I do not understand the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "id" inside "Widget"

Answer (score 0):

Look closer to your string: "W**id**get with **id**"

The first occurrence is found after "W..." which is the index of 1.

W  0

i  1 ✅

d  2

g  3

e  4

t  5

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to find the whole word, you can use a function something like this.

- Break the string into an array
- iterate through the array
- change each word into an array of chars
- iterate through the chars array and keep a running count of each letter
- increment your count by one after each word to account for the spaces
- stop the iteration when the word is found

```js
let str = 'Widget with id';

function findIndexOfWholeWord(str, searchStr){
  const words = str.split(' ')
  let numOfChars = 0
  
  for(let word of words){
   if(word === searchStr) break
    word.split('').forEach(char=>numOfChars++)
    numOfChars++
  }
  return numOfChars
}
console.log(findIndexOfWholeWord(str,'id')) //12
```